Python Django ASGI - memory leak - UPDATED #2
EDIT 25.04.2024:
malloc_trim(0) seems to work. I need to test how the server memory consumption looks like in the long run, though.
This is modified asgi.py which starts deamon thread which invokes malloc_trim(0) when threshold is reached.
import ctypes
import random
import time
from threading import Thread
import psutil
import os
import django
from django.core.handlers.asgi import ASGIHandler

MEMORY_THRESHOLD = 1024 * 1024 * 256  # 256MB


def trim_memory() -> int:
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
    return libc.malloc_trim(0)


def should_trim_memory() -> bool:
    # check if we're close to our OOM limit
    # through psutil
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return process.memory_info().rss > MEMORY_THRESHOLD


def trim_loop() -> None:
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.randint(30, 60))  # jitter between 30 and 60s
        if not should_trim_memory():
            continue

        ret = trim_memory()
        print("trim memory result: ", ret)


def get_asgi_application():
    """
    The public interface to Django's ASGI support. Return an ASGI 3 callable.

    Avoids making django.core.handlers.ASGIHandler a public API, in case the
    internal implementation changes or moves in the future.
    """

    django.setup(set_prefix=False)

    thread = Thread(name="TrimThread", target=trim_loop)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    return ASGIHandler()


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'v45.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()

EDIT 24.04.2024:
Fresh Django ASGI app is leaking.
That's related to this issue: TLS/SSL asyncio leaks memory
The person who reported the bug said Python 3.9 without uvloop doesn't leak or leaks smaller. I tried this config but unfortunately it didn't help. Can't check if Python 3.12 solves issue as Railway uses nixpacks with max version 3.11. If someone finds a config that doesn't leak, please share.
Steps to reproduce the problem:

Copy this repo: https://github.com/fifdee/djangofresh - just make sure to change ALLOWED_HOSTS and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in settings.py according to the domain Railway generates for you.
Host on Railway with custom start command in deploy section: hypercorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --reload djangofresh.asgi:application
Make sure you see 'Hello, world!' when visiting hosted app.
Run many concurrent requests from you local computer which will generate lots of inbound traffic. Make huge request body. Use the code below. Watch the memory consumption of your hosted app. Wait a moment after finishing the cycle. Repeat the cycle few times. After finishing the cycle, some memory will be released, but not all, so memory consumption will grow in time.

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests as requests
    
def get_server_response(params):
        url = 'https://djangofresh-production.up.railway.app/'
        with requests.Session() as s:
            r = s.get(url,
                      headers={
    
                      },
                      json=params)
    
            print(r.text[:100])
            return r.text
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        for _ in range(100):
            params = {
                'text': ' Very long text ' * 1000000,
            }
            executor.submit(get_server_response, params)


EDIT 18.04.2024:
It looks like the problem isn't connected with django-storages and images specifically, but requests generally.
Why? I made uploading images client-side with pre-signed URLs for upload and I'm only saving in my DB filenames, so knowing bucket and filename I can retrieve image URL using pre-signed URLs for download. This way no images go through Django server, which is nice.
However, memory consumption is still rising. Much, much slower, but still.
Next step? After processing images with AWS Lambda function I was sending response to my Django server with output image URL, thumbnail URL, and thumbnail base64 version. So I removed base64 thumbnail from the response. Guess what? Memory consumption is now rising but again - slower than when base64 thumbnail was included in the response.
This clearly shows that there's some kind of memory leak with every request coming through the Django server. The bigger size of request / response, the bigger and faster is memory leak.

Old description:
First of all I've been looking for a solution for a couple of days and tried various code snippets found here.
The problem: hosted web app consumes more and more memory everytime image is saved to a Django model ImageField set up with S3 via django-storages.
What I tried or observed: no matter which ASGI server I used, result was the same (Daphne, Uvicorn, Hypercorn, Granian). I checked memory allocation line by line in cricital places with tracemalloc and the memory consumption rised specifically after saving images.
    async def upload_image(content_img, content_thumbnail):
        lf1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        for chunk in content_img.chunks():
            lf1.write(chunk)

        lf2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        for chunk in content_thumbnail.chunks():
            lf2.write(chunk)

        uploaded_image = await UploadedImage.objects.acreate(user=request.user, type=type, app_name=app_name)

        def upload_image_sync():
            uploaded_image.image.save(content_img.name, lf1)
            uploaded_image.thumbnail.save(content_thumbnail.name, lf2)

        await sync_to_async(upload_image_sync)()

In above code invoking 'uploaded_image.image.save' or 'uploaded_image.thumbnail.save' shows higher memory usage with tracemalloc, pointing 'json/decoder.py' as the file which occupies memory.
And here's the interesting part. Saving image to model shows ~10MB more memory used and jumps from ~45MB to ~55MB. If I save lots of images in short period of time, I saw spikes up to ~400MB, but after that the current usage lowered and it looked like memory was released. Not always going back to 45MB but after completing many requests it looked good, like garbage collector working as supposed. These logs from tracemalloc were similar on local machine and hosted server.
However, the memory usage statistics from web server host are completely different. I understand that tracemalloc probably shows only memory usage from Django web app and the hosted container includes other parts like ASGI web server. But it looked like this (1 worker): starting at ~250MB, after invoking parts which upload image to S3 memory usage of the container went up by ~50-100MB per one image uploaded. The worst part is that memory is not being released (sometimes it looked like it was releasing 10% of the original amount which went up during requests in short period of time). As a result I was able to run out of 8GB server memory in 2 minutes if I made a stress test with lots of images.
I use railway.app to host web app, but I also checked render.com if it behaves the same, and it does. One quite big difference however is when I use hypercorn --workers 5 --max-requests 50 --max-requests-jitter 25 . Restarting workers on railway.app doesn't release memory at all (!) but it does on render.com. Restarting workers unfortunately was leading to dropping some requests so it doesn't look like solution for my problem, even if I choose render.com as a primary host.
Did anyone encounter such a problem and solved it?
Maybe there's a way to force saving images in S3 in chunks if that's the cause? Or maybe the external layers of hosted container don't release the memory when requests come?

What is content_img and content_thumbnail? Is that a file? Are you closing it?

They are files inside request.FILES - TemporaryUploadedFiles specifically. Nothing to close there.

Did the server actually run out of memory or did the server grab available memory?

When tested on railway.app it somehow didn't crash, just kept max memory at 8GB and expected expenses at the end of month went to the sky. So it probably assigned more memory than current plan suggests. When tested on render.com, the server just crashed after reaching max memory for current plan and had to restart.

I updated the topic and description as new facts showed up.

@MattSeymour do web servers behave like that? They grab what's available and don't bother with freeing the memory up? Asking because I'm also facing similar problem

@Enirsa Not yet. I'm going to trim the project removing unused libraries (which shouldn't have any impact if they're not invoked in the code I guess) and update everything to latest versions. If that doesn't help I think I'll have to do the other way - start with fresh Django ASGI project and start adding libraries and functionality one by one, testing everytime how memory consumption looks like.

Your server processes will consume memory available to them if it's there. Its not always going to release the memory either unless the system requests it back.

Edited the post once again - problem related to asyncio itself.

@Enirsa Try if malloc_trim(0) works for you. Details at the beginning of the original question.
